# Sequential/Parallel and Synchronous/Asynchronous

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing

If I understand correctly, concurrent tasks can be sequential or parallel and can be synchronous or asynchronous.

Can you give an example of each of the four possibilities? I think NodeJS async/await would be sequential asynchronous.

And where would multithreading fall? I cannot find out whether threads are synchronous or not online, the search results are polluted with unrelated questions.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "sequential?" Normally I would think of "sequential" as meaning the opposite of "concurrent." Things that happen sequentially happen in a definite order. Things that happen concurrently happen in no particular order. I'm _guessing_ that the idea you are shooting for is, concurrency-without-parallelism, which is what you get if you run multiple threads on a machine that has only one CPU to run them. I don't know of a special name for that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes you are correct, I used sequential as "non-parallel" or "single-core", *some* sub-tasks (possibly from different tasks) are executed sequentially

Comment: So, one example of concurrent-but-not-parallel would be what I said above: Two or more threads running concurrently with each other, and only one CPU available to execute their code. That's a thing I encountered often when I was writing code for embedded systems where my code ran on tiny [_microcontrollers_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller). On the flip-side, a parallel-but-synchronous computation sounds like something that would happen on [_vector processors_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor) or, on some specialized, application-specific computing hardware.